# Is it possible to shift or swap elements position in a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    for _ in range(n): #n is the number of inputs
        queue = dict(x.split() for x in input().splitlines())
        #queue is a dict that splits the input and store the input as key and value pair.
        for key,value in queue.items():
            print(value,end=' ')
```

Using dictionary as queue to shift or swap elements position in a dictionary in Python

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries in Python are unordered (or at least, they should be). In Python 3.6 or later, dictionaries print out in the order they were added, but you should always treat dictionaries as though they are completely unordered. You can't move values around in a dictionary because, simply put, they aren't in any order! If you want to order them, sort the dict.keys() list yourself.

More info here: http://www.pythonlikeyoumeanit.com/Module2_EssentialsOfPython/DataStructures_II_Dictionaries.html#Are-Dictionaries-Ordered?-A-Word-of-Warning

Comment: According to [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ordereddict-in-python/), you can use `collections.OrderedDict()`, when you need order to be guaranteed on older versions of python, and guaranteed order became more than just an implementation detail in version 3.7.

Comment: The `OrderedDict` is a valuable tool, but even that will only preserve insertion order, so the dictionary still can't be reordered. It's also not amazing practice to rely on the ordering of the built-in dict, and if you need it sorted you should rely on `OrderedDict`. Either way, it unfortunately doesn't resolve the original question